# Creating Chunk Generator from request stream - Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am running Python and Flask with Flask-restful on my server. I want to handle streaming data upload to my server. I have set up an endpoint as follows:

```py
class ChunkProcessor(Resource):
    j = 0
    def chunk_fun(self):
        chunk_size = int(request.headers.get("x-chunk-size"))
        chunk = request.stream.read(chunk_size)
        self.j = 0
        while chunk:
            print("got chunk")
            yield chunk
            self.j += 1
            chunk = request.stream.read(chunk_size)
    def post(self):
        for i in self.chunk_fun():
            pass
        return {"success": "TRUE", "n_chunks": self.j}
```

In this form it is working fine.

But now I want to send these chunks off to multiple destinations. i.e. As follows:

```py
class ChunkProcessor(Resource):
    def chunk_fun(self):
        chunk_size = int(request.headers.get("x-chunk-size"))
        chunk = request.stream.read(chunk_size)
        while chunk:
            yield chunk
            chunk = request.stream.read(chunk_size)
    def post(self):
        res1 = MyAPI1().call(self.chunk_fun)
        res2 = MyAPI2().call(self.chunk_fun)
        return {"success": "TRUE", "output": [res1, res2]}
```

In the current form, the request stream is exhausted by the first call.

Ideally, I would like to pass a `chunk generator` to each of my API interfaces.

The goal is to create a chunk generator function from the request stream in Flask. Additionally, I plan on running my API calls from seperate threads.

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!